# How can i build keras character level model using the SimpleRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need help to build character level SimpleRNN model using the keras and tensorflow as backend. What I am trying to do is ask the model to predict the next character. Suppose 'StackOverflow' if we pass 'S' it should predict 't'. Here one word is one sequence with stop and start padding. The problem I am facing issue while training and testing the model because both the training and target data have the same shape. The code is in the gits. Any help or comments are appreciated.
https://gist.github.com/chatrapathik/71c4dcef6cec417393f13ee4e117f9c5

Comment: Have a look at existing Keras [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to predict a single next character, You can use the training data as a target data by just shifting each character one index to the left. In python if you have numpy arrays of train_data you can do the following.

```
test_data = train_data[1:]
```

Since you are not using the last characters in train data you can remove it

```
train_data = train_data[:-1]
```